# trying to fetch data from 2 different collections from same database in mongodb

Tags: javascript, html, css, mongodb, ejs

I am unable to display data from 2 different collections . From `Enterdetails` collection, I have to display `name` , `age`, `blood_group` , `medical_history` and `phone_number` and from `Index` collection, I have to display date in the same frontend (`patients.ejs`) . I am able to display the `Enterdetails` info but in place of date it shows invalid date.

this is `app.js` code for fetching data into the `patient.ejs` file

```js
function formatDate(date) {
  const options = {
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'long',
    day: 'numeric'
  };
  return new Date(date).toLocaleDateString(undefined, options);
}

app.get('/patients', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const indexData = await Index.find({}).exec();
    const enterDetailsData = await Enterdetails.find({}).exec();

    res.render('patients', {
      enterDetailsData,
      indexData,
      formatDate
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.send(error);
  }
});
```

This is the code for `patients.ejs`

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Age</th>
  <th>Blood Group</th>
  <th>Phone Number</th>
  <th>Medical History</th>
  <th>Date</th>
 </tr>
 <% enterDetailsData.forEach(function(data) { %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= data.name %></td>
    <td><%= data.age %></td>
    <td><%= data.blood_group %></td>
    <td><%= data.phone_number %></td>
    <td><%= data.medical_history %></td>
    <td><%= formatDate(data.date). %></td>
  </tr>
<% }); %>
</table>
```

This is the code for `index_schema.js`

```js
const indexSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minLength: 1,
    maxLength: 50,
    pattern: /^[a-zA-Z ]*$/
  },
  date: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    validate: {
      validator: function(value) {
        if (validator.isDate(value)) {
          var date = new Date(value);
          return date.getTime() >= Date.now();
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      },
      message: 'Invalid date',
    }
  },
  phone_number: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    minlength: 10,
    maxlength: 10,
    Validate(value) {
      if (!validator.isMobilePhone(value)) {
        throw new Error(alert("mobile number is invalid"));
      }
    }
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    require: true,
    minlength: 4,
    maxlength: 16
  }
});
```

This is the code for `enterdetails_schema.js`

```js
const enterdetailsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minLength: 1,
    maxLength: 50,
    pattern: /^[a-zA-Z ]*$/
  },
  age: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  blood_group: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  phone_number: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    minlength: 10,
    maxlength: 10,
    Validate(value) {
      if (!validator.isMobilePhone(value)) {
        throw new Error("mobile number is invalid");
      }
    }
  },
  medical_history: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 4,
    maxlength: 16
  }
});
```

I was trying to display the `date` from `Index` collection but it shows `invalid`[image]

Comment: use the aggregate() function fetch data from 2 different collections from same database in mongodb

Comment: can you me how to use it in my code? I am new to this!

Comment: How do you identify the appropriate `Index` document from each `Enterdetails` document?

Comment: I am trying to selectively display the values from the 2 collections in the same frontend. From Index, I want to display date only and from Enterdetails, I want to display  name , age , phone_number , blood_group , and Medical_history .